# Typescript problem when accessing prisma model property

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, prisma

I'm fairly new to using Prisma with NestJS and GraphQL, and I cannot get rid of a TS warning when trying to access one of my model properties.

Here I'm trying to retrieve a datasource record, and convert a json to a base64 string. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
  async findOne(data: Prisma.DatasourceWhereUniqueInput) {
    const datasource = await this.prisma.datasource.findUnique({
      where: { id: data.id },
    });

    const { serviceAccountJson } = datasource;

    datasource.serviceAccountJson = Buffer.from(
      JSON.stringify(serviceAccountJson),
    ).toString('base64');

    return datasource;
  }
```

And this is the error I get on my local server:
[image]

I can get rid of this by adding a @ts-ignore but I feel like it's not really clean to do so.

This is how my Datasource model looks like in my schema.prisma file

```
model Datasource {
  id                  Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  serviceAccountJson  Json?
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with the name of your `Datasource` model conflicting with the Prisma Schema's concept of a `datasource`.

I would open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.yml) about this but you could work around it by changing your model name.